# Recargar datatable al borrar registro

Tags: ajax, datatable

tengo el siguiente inconveniente tengo dos scripts un trae el listado de datos de una consulta la función  se llama listar() y  en otro script se llama funcion eliminar (), todo bien pero cuando borro el registro tengo que actualizar la pagina para que se vea el resultado, necesito que saque el registro de la tabla sin recargar la pagina. Muchas gracias Adjunto el primer script de listar el cual llama desde la ultima columna a la funcion eliminar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function listar(){
    var idarea = document.getElementById('idarea').value;
    var fechah = document.getElementById('Fechahasta').value;
    var fechad = document.getElementById('Fechadesde').value;
    if (fechad > fechah || fechah == fechad || fechah == '' || fechad == '' ){
      alertify.alert("Atención","Rango de fechas incorrectos");
      return false;
    }
    else{

      $("#titulo").show();
      $("#movimiento").show();
      var combo = document.getElementById('area').value;

      document.getElementById("ctexto").innerHTML='Listado de entradas de productos'+'-'+combo;


      var table = $("#movimiento").DataTable({

        "destroy": true,

        "order": [0, 'desc'],
        "ajax": {
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "data/getent.php",

          "data": function (d) {
            return $.extend({}, d, {
              "idarea": $('#idarea').val(),
              "fechah": $('#Fechahasta').val(),
              "fechad": $('#Fechadesde').val()
            });
          }
        },
        "columns": [{
          "data": "id"
        }, {
          "data": "name"
        }, {
          "data": "cant"
        }, {
          "data": "fecha"
        }, {
          "data": "receptor"
        }, {
          "data": "usuario"
        }, {
          "data": "remito"
        }, {
          "data": "expediente"},

          {"targets": -1,
          "data": null,
          "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
            if(type === 'display'){
              data = '<div class="text-center" class="btn-group" ><a  href="#"  onclick="eliminar('+ full['id'] +') " ><i class="fas fa-trash-alt  fa-2x" title="Consultar" style="text-align: center; "></i></a></div>';
            }

            return data;

          }}
          ],
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
      { extend: 'print',

       footer: true,  exportOptions: { columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7 ],format: {
        body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
            return column === 1,2,3 ?
                data.toUpperCase():
                data;
        }
    } } },
      { extend: 'excelHtml5', footer: true,  exportOptions: { columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7 ],format: {
        body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
            return column === 1,2,3 ?
                data.toUpperCase():
                data;
        }
    } } },
      { extend: 'pdfHtml5', footer: true, exportOptions: { columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7 ],format: {
        body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
            return column === 1,2,3 ?
                data.toUpperCase():
                data;
        }
    } } }
      ],
        "language": idioma_es

    });



}
}
var idioma_es = {
    "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
    "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
    "sEmptyTable":     "NingÃºn dato disponible en esta tabla",
    "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
    "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
    "sInfoPostFix":    "",
    "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
    "sUrl":            "",
    "sInfoThousands":  ",",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "oPaginate": {
      "sFirst":    "Primero",
      "sLast":     "Ãšltimo",
      "sNext":     "Siguiente",
      "sPrevious": "Anterior"
    },
    "oAria": {
      "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
      "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
    }
  }

</script>

// Función eliminar llamada desde la función listar

<script type="text/javascript">
  function eliminar(id){
 var table = $('#movimiento').DataTable();

    var id = id;
     var conf = confirm("¿Está seguro, realmente desea eliminar el registro?");
    if (conf == true) {

      var Fechadesde= document.getElementById('Fechadesde').value;
      var Fechahasta= document.getElementById('Fechahasta').value;
      var idarea= document.getElementById('idarea').value;



    $.ajax({

      type:"POST",
      url:"deletent.php",
      data:"id="+id+"&Fechadesde="+Fechadesde+"&Fechahasta="+Fechahasta+"&idarea="+idarea,
      success: function (data){

         table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );



      }

    });
  }


  }



</script>
```

//No se como puedo actualizar sin recargar la pagina cada vez que borro registro

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera volvi a llamar a la función listar() desde la funcion eliminar()

```
success: function (data){

         listar();



      }
```

Comment: Agrega una explicación para darle mayor calidad a tu propia respuesta, considera que hay más usuarios con un escenario similar, puedes ser el héroe de todos ellos :D